# WiX bootstrapper - disable a control using HexStyle

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, wix3.8

I have a WiX bootstrapper theme xml file, and I want to permanently disable a control. I have tried to set `HexStyle` to the value of `WS_DISABLED` ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). However the control is still enabled. Anyone knows if I can use `HexStyle` or know of another way of having a control permanently disabled. I use the `WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense` BootstrapperApplication.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The possible solution is to find Id of this control and then create Variable with postfix "State". I hope it should work:

```
<Variable Name="EulaRicheditState" Type="string" Value="disable" />
```

Comment: Great find. How did you figure this out?

Comment: Oh boy! it was almost 5 years ago. I just remember I was taking a look at source code of WIX Toolset and found such logic. Unfortunately, I can't say now where exactly it was. I think it is kind of not-documented tricky feature :)

Comment: Wow! I've been looking to do this for days! Mucho appreciated.